# Need help on understanding the relatively open set.

Tags: real-analysis

So, the definition of a relatively open set is:

> A set E is said to be relatively open in $D\subseteq V$, a normed
>   vector space, provided there exists an open set $U\subseteq V$ such
>   that $E=U\cap D$. Similarly, a set $E$ is said to be relatively closed
>   in $D\subseteq V$ provided there exists a closed set $K\subseteq V$
>   such that $E=K\cap D$.

But if $D$ was a close set, then would $E$ be a still relatively open set if $D$ was wholly contained in $U$? If I draw the picture, it seems like $U\cap D$ is not an open set but a closed set. On the other hand, if $U$ was wholly contained in $D$ I can see that it certainly is an open set. Are these two examples equal in terms of being relatively open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $D$ is "wholly contained" in $U$, i.e. $D \subset U$. Then $E=U\cap D$ implies $E=D$. In this case, $E$ is both open and closed as it comprises the entire space $D$.